# Cannot access a disposed object while using OracleCommand in using loop. The async method is called through Task.Run() many times

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

This ia my async method which is called 1 000 000 times through `Task.Run()` and checking each task status later time:

```
private static async Task ExecuteOracleCommandAsync(DataTable schemaTable, OracleConnection oraConn, string insertString, object[][] obj, OracleParameter[] param)
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = oraConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = string.Concat(insertString, ")");
                cmd.ArrayBindCount = obj[0].Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
                }

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
```

I get the error:

> C# TPL issue: Cannot access a disposed object while using OracleCommand in using loop

Comment: is Task.Run() is part of any loop? can you also show code block of how async method is called.

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Is that the *actual* error message? .NET wouldn't display this. It would display `Cannot access a disposed object` but not `C# TPL issue:` or `while using OracleCommand in using loop`. The OracleCommand object doesn't know it's being called in a loop

Comment: BTW if you want to insert 1M rows, *DON'T* execute 1M INSERT commands. It could end up being orders of magnitude slower. Use whatever bulk insertion mechanism is offered by your provider (there are several Oracle providers, even by Oracle itself), eg [OracleBulkCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm#ODPNT7446) in ODP.NET. Those classes use Oracle's own bulk insertion mechanism which ensures streaming of the data to the server, fast import and minimal logging

Comment: Yes, Task.Run() is part of loop.

Comment: Error is: Cannot access a disposed object

Comment: List<Task> insert = new List<Task>();                                
insert.Add(Task.Run(() => ExecuteOracleCommandAsync(schemaTable, oraConn, insertString, obj, param)));                                                                         insert is being called 1 million times. All these events happen in a single transaction, since if any record is junk we need to rollback the entire transaction.